# Use a different diff command with CVS?

Tags: diff, cvs, meld

Is it possible to use a different diff program with CVS?  I'd like to use something like meld to give me a side-by-side graphical view of the repository and my changes.  It's out of my control to use a different CMS.  What would be ideal is some undocumented command line argument that would work like this:

```
cvs diff -prog /usr/bin/meld foo.cc
```

This would give me a diff of my checked out, modified version of foo.cc with the repository version, but using the diff program meld.

I realize an undocumented command line argument is unlikely, so if you have to hack it together, that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the [cvsmenu plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1245) for Vim.  It works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use tkcvs and tkdiff (not the lastest version either)

- http://www.twobarleycorns.net/tkcvs.html
- http://tkdiff.sourceforge.net/
- http://wiki.tcl.tk/3773

the cool thing is that tkcvs also supports subversion.

tkdiff works on the command line and takes cvs tags...

- tkdiff -rfoo_v5_0 -rfoo_v6_5 silly.c (compare two different versions than the one in your local directory)
- tkdiff spring.h (compare my local version to the repository)
- tkdiff -r1.6 happy.c (compare my local version  to a specific repository version)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Is there any documentation available for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [WinCVS](http://www.wincvs.org/), you can setup a Diff application such as [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) in the preferences.

In WinCVS preferences, tab WinCVS, "External diff program"

Comment: Useful for those on Windows, but I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Meld supports this natively.  See "Working Copy" [screenshot](http://meld.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html) from [meld.sourceforge.net](http://meld.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Yes, but it's horribly documented.  I can't find where I specify where the repository lives.  My current method is to type the long path beyond $CVSROOT to the directory that matches my current working directory.

Comment: meld foo.cc $CVSROOT/dir1/dir2/dir3/foo.cc,v

Comment: So how do you automate this, so that you just execute `whatever foo.cc` and it knowns where to look for the unmodified version?