# cvs: updates fail to merge

Tags: version-control, merge, cvs

I've just discovered, a surprising for me behavior of cvs.

- I change file1 localy
- During this time people change other unrelated parts of the same file, and commit to the repository
- I update my local copy from repository
- At this point I expect my local copy of file1 to contain all changes made by others to this file, unless the update above reported a conflict. However, when I do now diff with head, I discover lot's of differences coming from changes made by others in parts of the file that I did not touch at all.

Any ideas? Is this just the limited abilities of cvs to merge? Any wrong setting? Something in my workflow?

Answer (score 1):

CVS has very limited merge facilities. Switch to a modern system such as Git (perhaps via `git-cvsimport` if the repo maintainer is uncooperative) if you want a better merge experience. See also [Best practices for using git with CVS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595106/best-practices-for-using-git-with-cvs)

Comment: Hmmm... Any way to ask cvs to use an external merge tool?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but requires CVS support un the tool, or a CVS wrapper of some sort. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631781/use-a-different-diff-command-with-cvs for some options.

Comment: It seems the tools mentioned on your above link support only viewing the differences in an external tool.  Is there anything that can *merge* with an external tool?

Comment: My impression is that e.g. Meld can do that too, but I haven't tried it (long-time Emacs user, long since migrated from CVS to SVN and on to Darcs and Git).  My suggestion would be to post a separate question because this discussion is basically only seen by you and me.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution is :

> **1. Save your local code to another place manually**
>
> **2. Revert the files which may has conflict to the HEAD (most latest) version on CVS server.**
>
> **3. Add back your change to the Reverted file.**

The concept for above solution is to CLEAR UP all the possible issue by REVERT and get a 100% clean version from repository then add back our changes.

It can resolve below issues which caused by code out of date / code base messed up.

> 1. CVS commit had a conflict and has not been modified
> 2. CVS update failed
> 3. CVS not sync