# using an external merge tool with cvs

Tags: version-control, merge, cvs

How can I configure cvs to use an external merge tool instead of it's own limited one?

I'm using tortoisecvs on Windows as the client

Comment: This question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631781/use-a-different-diff-command-with-cvs. Or have a look at Meld: https://live.gnome.org/Meld/Windows