# How can I use meld as the cvs difference viewer?

Tags: cvs, meld

I'm using to visualizing diff results using the nice graphical meld application - when my source control uses mercurial or git.

Now I'm stuck with maintaining a codebase using CVS; but I still want to use meld. i.e. instead of looking at `cvs diff`, I want to have a meld window come up with the root of the modified and the committed versions.

How do I do this?

<sub>Related question: [Use a different diff command with CVS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631781/use-a-different-diff-command-with-cvs)
 ... but while answers there suggest using meld is possible, there's no explanation how.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps newer versions of meld have dropped CVS support. You can always write a wrapper function that checks out the old version to a temp location and uses meld to diff against that.